# colorbox with address bar

Tags: colorbox

I am a javascript dummy. I downloaded colorbox and jquery. They work great. I followed tutorials and read the example code but I cant figure this out.
When I open a colorbox ,it opens to the correct url, I can then click links in the box and surf other sites. That is all great. I need to have the url show in a address block at the top of the window.   When I use a java popup it will work fine. You can goto other urls and the address shows in the address bar at the top of the window. 
So I assume that I can do it with colorbox. This would make my page look much better than a plain popup. Can this be done. here is my code.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">             </script>
          <script src="http://www.mysite.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.mysite.com/colorbox/colorbox.css"    />




<script>
parent.jQuery.colorbox.close();
    $(function ()
    {

        $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});

})




   </script>
```

and my link to open the box

```
<a class='iframe' href="http://www.ebay.com">ebay </a></p>
```

If you chooes to help I beg you to show me where the new code go's. If you tell me to add a line of code I will not understand where to put it. I am trying hard to learn javascript but I am a very newbe. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ColorBox is the right plugin for you to use, given its default design and your skill set.  ColorBox is not designed to be "browser like" and let the user surf to other sites.

It is possible to change that design assumption, but it would require more advanced JS skills than you admit to.

Maybe you can achieve your aim by simply opening a new browser instance using a plain HTML anchor tag (`<a>`) and using the "target=" parameter.

Best,

KJM

Comment: Thanks. I have reached the same conclusion.